# Code behind is passing wrong value to application

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I'm trying to display a specific hyperlink in my gridview based on the value of a column.

Here's my GridView:
[image: Image showing the GridView]

Code Behind:

```
Protected Sub TaxSaleGridView_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles TaxSaleGridView.RowDataBound

    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        OPval = DirectCast(e.Row.DataItem, Data.DataRowView)("OtherParcel").ToString()


       Select Case OPval

            Case Is <> Nothing
                existsOtherParcel = "Y"
                e.Row.Cells(3).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow

            Case Is = Nothing
                existsOtherParcel = "N"
                e.Row.Cells(3).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.YellowGreen
                e.Row.Cells(3).Text = TaxSaleGridView.Rows.Count

        End Select

    End If
```

End Sub

My HTML:

```
             <%If existsOtherParcel = "Y" Then%>
                Other Parcel Exists? <%Response.Write(existsOtherParcel)%><br /><br />
                <asp:HyperLink ID="OtherParcelHyperLink" runat="server"                     

                    NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("OtherParcel", "http://URL/index.html?parcel={0}") %>' 
                    Text="Location Map" Target="_blank" onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href, '','toolbar=yes,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,copyhistory=yes,width=780,height=550,left=20,top=20');">

                </asp:HyperLink><br />

                <asp:Label ID="notOnSale" runat="server" Text="Land is not on sale." Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label><br /><br />

             <%ElseIf existsOtherParcel = "N" Then%>
               Other Parcel Exists? <%Response.Write(existsOtherParcel)%><br /><br />
                <asp:HyperLink ID="LocationMapHyperLink" runat="server" 

                    NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Property_ID", "http://URL/index.html?parcel={0}") %>' 
                    Text="Location Map" Target="_blank" onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href, '','toolbar=yes,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,copyhistory=yes,width=780,height=550,left=20,top=20');">

                </asp:HyperLink><br /><br />

              <%End If%>




                <asp:HyperLink ID="PRCHyperLink" runat="server" 
                    NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("UnformattedParcelNumber", "http://URL/default.asp?sparcelno={0}&stemp=&dSearch=houseno&dreport=propcard&report=&dReportName=Property Card") %>' 
                    Text="Property Record Card" Target="_blank" onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href, '','toolbar=yes,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,copyhistory=yes,width=780,height=550,left=20,top=20');">
                </asp:HyperLink>

            </ItemTemplate>                


        </asp:TemplateField>
```

There are only 3 occurrences in which the `OtherParcel` column will have a value... the rest are blank.  My goal is to have the `Location Map` hyperlink in the `Reference Materials` column point to the `OtherParcel` value if it exists, or otherwise point to the Sale ID if it doesn't.  However, all the links point to the Sale ID even though the the OtherParcel value exists for given rows. 
 
 
As you can see in the gridview, the cells in the "OtherParcel" column are changing colors as expected.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Not an all out answer but a few things to checkout.  Firstly it seems to me thatOPval will always be <> Nothing because it is cast as a string, hence existsOtherParcel will always be "Y".  However I think when the event is captured, the row has already been rendered so it's tool late for your existsOtherParcel to be acted on.  I think you need to apply your URL changes to the already rendered row much like you have done for colours.

Comment: So, you're saying that I should set the [NavigateUrl] value to either "OtherParcel" or "Property_ID" in the code behind?

Comment: Yeah.  Change your cases though - You should be comparing against an empty string rather than Nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You might as well do it all in code behind:

```
Select Case OPval

Case Is <> Nothing
    existsOtherParcel = "Y"
    e.Row.Cells(3).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow
    OtherParcelHyperLink.NavigateUrl = String.Format("http://URL/index.html?parcel={0}", OtherParcel)

Case Is = Nothing
    existsOtherParcel = "N"
    e.Row.Cells(3).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.YellowGreen
    e.Row.Cells(3).Text = TaxSaleGridView.Rows.Count
    LocationMapHyperLink.NavigateUrl = String.Format("http://URL/index.html?parcel={0}", Property_ID)

End Select
```

Comment: I added the "OtherParcelHyperLink.NavigateUrl" portion to the first Case, but I get the following error: 
"OtherParcelHyperLink is not declared.  It may be inaccessible due to its protection level."

Comment: OK, Intellisense is recognizing "OtherParcelHyperLink" now... but when I run it, I get this error:  "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: @jschmidt strange, it should not be null